# DAX Measure to pull out the question with the highest average score

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a DAX Measure in Power BI to pull out the question with the highest average score. It's a very simple table, just question, person and score.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say you have such a table:

```
question       person       score
Question 01     Emma          10
Question 02     Luis          12
Question 01     Becky          4
Question 03     Jack          13
Question 02     William       15
Question 04     John           9
Question 02     David          6
Question 01     Joe           11
Question 04     Oscar         10
Question 03     Lyudmila       5
```

Then Here is your DAX Code as measure:

```
Highest_Average_Score = 
VAR TblAvgScore = ADDCOLUMNS(
                    VALUES(Tbl[question]),
                    "AvgScore",CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Tbl[score])))
VAR TblMaxAvg = MAXX(TblAvgScore,[AvgScore])
VAR TblQuestion = MAXX(
                    FILTER(TblAvgScore,[AvgScore] = TblMaxAvg),[question])
RETURN
    TblQuestion
```

If you put it on a visual card:

[image: Highest Score]

Bonus : We can make a quick check to test our result:

[image: GRE]

I hope It solves your problem.